# Проблема с функцией(C++, структуры)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, структуры-данных

[image: версия с указателем - рабочая]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct aeroflot
{
    char* fname;
    int fnumber;
    char* ptype;

};
void input(aeroflot obj)
{
    char* buffer = new char[255];
    cout << "название пункта назначения рейса: " << endl;
    cin >> buffer;
    obj.fname = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
    strcpy(obj.fname, buffer);
    obj.fname[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    cout << "номер рейса (число): " << endl;
    cin >> obj.fnumber;
    cout << "тип самолета: " << endl;
    cin >> buffer;
    obj.ptype = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
    strcpy(obj.ptype, buffer);
    obj.ptype[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
{
 aeroflot plane = {};
 input(plane);
 system("pause");
}
```

Если вытащить из под функции все работает, в функции же (Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00254B31 в lab4.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.) Однако, эта же версия с указателем работает(картинка1), помогите разобраться, пожалуйста =3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А код с картинки вы предлагаете нам вручную набивать? Не поленитесь сделать минимальный компилируемый пример. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: понял, сделано!

Comment: кстати, другая версия работает, здесь я передаю указатель и все в порядке

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы передаёте вашу структуру в функцию *по значению*. То есть, в функцию приходит **копия** структуры, она там как-то заполняется, а оригинал структуры остаётся незаполненным.

Из-за этого все проблемы.

Передавайте, например, указатель или ссылку на структуру, будет всё работать.

P. S.: Остаток кода не смотрел.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: @dahbka: Пожалуйста!